# Get Selected Index Using ICheck Radio Button in ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, icheck

```
<tr ng-repeat="school in schools">
 <td>{{school.Location}}</td>
 <td>{{school.Type}}</td>
 <td>{{school.Name}}</td>
 <td class="school-action text-center">
     <label>                             
           <input type="radio" name="masdoc-school" class="flat-red" />
     </label>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I have already defined Icheck

```
$('input[type="radio"].flat-red').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'
});
```

$scope.schools is an array object, how can I get selected index of input[name="masdoc-school"] to get a value of $scope.schools[selected index] in controller. Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solve! Using icheck directive of (wajatimur) at https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/issues/62

```
app.directive('icheck', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                var value;
                value = $attrs['value'];

                $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function(newValue) {
                    $(element).iCheck('update');
                })

                return $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'

                }).on('ifChanged', function(event) {
                    if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            return ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.checked);
                        });
                    }
                    if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                        return $scope.$apply(function() {
                            return ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

then in ng-repeat:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="school in schools">
       <td>{{school.Location}}</td>
       <td>{{school.Type}}</td>
       <td>{{school.Name}}</td>
       <td class="school-action text-center">
          <label>
               <input icheck type="radio" name="iCheck" class="flat-red" ng-value={{$index}} ng-model="$parent.schoolIndex" ng-change="changeFaculty(schoolIndex)"/>
          </label>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

using $parent in ng-model because ngRepeat will create new scopes for its children (along with how prototypal inheritance affects scopes) so ng-change will only fires event once.